# Python extract substring from string

Tags: python

so i'm trying to convert a bash script, that i wrote, into python, that i'm learning, and the python equivalent of the bash whois just can't give me the answer that i need.

this is what i have in bash-

```
whois 'ip address' | grep -i abuse | \
     grep -o [[:alnum:]]*\@[[:alnum:]]*\.[[:alpha:]]* | sort -u
```

and it works perfectly.

when trying to do something similar in python(3.5.2)-

```
IPWhois('ip address').lookup_whois()
```

it's giving me a dictionary with the object that i'm looking for in the first value about half way through the string.

i have tried to put it into `str(dict).splice('\n')[index]`, yet with each iteration the index changes so i can't put it into a script like that. also the bash whois can do both ip addresses and domain names with out having to convert.
i think that i have figured out the conversion, yet trying to grab the results from the IPWhois is giving me a pain in the butt.

i could call the bash `whois` from `subprocess.call`, yet would like to figure out how to do it in python.  i know that i can grab part of it with `re.configure`, yet again the return changes so `re.compile` would have to change each time also.

do i keep trying or do i just stick with the bash script that works so well?
i have already written most of the python script and the things that i have to look up are helping me learn.

any ideas?

you can see the bash script [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwhDqxZzf5XHWk9nSTdLc2FiX28)

thanks,
em

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right track with using the regex module. Your [search](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.search) could be

```
re.search(r'(\w*@\w*\.\w*)', IPWhois(ip).lookup_whois()['nets'][0]['emails']).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was

```
domain = socket.gethostbyname(hostname/ipaddr) #if ipaddr it stays the same
email_addr = re.search(r'(\w*\D\w*@\w*\.\w*)', IPWhois(domain).lookup_whois()['nets'][0]['emails']).group(1)
```

I had to put the extra `\w*\D` in there because some of the email addresses had a hyphen in them. I was looking at the regex-howto instead of the full library.